# Wireshark: Custom dissector info field not always shown

Tags: wireshark-dissector

I've wrote some LUA custom dissector which is integrated into 2 PCs (think different OS) running same wireshark version 2.6.2.

- on one PC, I can see in the info column my data.
- on the other, the column is empty.

Do you have any suggestion what could be the issue and how to solve the it?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm throwing some ideas:

- You are using a type that only one OS recognizes properly
- You have some memory/CPU issue on one PC and the dissector cannot
  complete    whatever it's doing
- Your .lua file isn't the same - check it (via MD5ing preferably)
- You have two functions/dissectors with the same name on one PC and it doesn't do what you wish